# window.onbeforeunload in firefox 7.0.1

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using this code to display some msg before tab is closed in firefox:

```
function callUnloadFunction(){
    return "Hello world"; 
}
...
window.onbeforeunload = callUnloadFunction;
```

However, the msg that is displayed is not "Hello world". has firefox stopped listening to that event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jQuery's [unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) event.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the event in your function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
      e = e || window.event;

      // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
      if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Any string';
      }

      // For Safari
      return 'Any string';
    };
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload